# related rate problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

One plane is flying south from toronto at 900 kilometres per hour while a second plane at the same altitude is flying south-west from toronto at 800 kilometres per hour. How fast are the two planes separating when the first plane is 400 kilometres from toronto and the second plane is 700 kilometres from toronto ?

My answer was :

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 900 \; ; \; \frac{dy}{dt} = 800 \; and \; find \; \frac{dz}{dt} \; when \; x=400 \; ; \; y=700 $

$$ z^2 = y^2 - x^2 $$

$$ z = \sqrt{(700)^2-(400)^2} = 574.456 $$

$$ \frac{dz}{dt}2z=\frac{dy}{dt}2y-\frac{dx}{dt}2x $$

$$ \frac{dz}{dt}(2)(574.456)=(800)(2)(700)-(900)(2)(400) $$

$$ \frac{dz}{dt} = 348.155 km/hr $$

The answer in the book is 492.6 km/h So what's wrong with my solution ?

Comment: The triangle whose vertices are Toronto and the two planes is not a right triangle.

Comment: So what is it ? the question says two planes moved from the same place one to south and the other one to south-west. Can you explain to me how is it gonna be ?

Comment: If $T$ is Toronto, and $P$ and $Q$ are the planes, then $\angle PTQ=\frac{\pi}4$; now use the cosine law to find $z^2$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I'm confused a little bit. Why $∠PTQ = \frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: Because that’s the angle between south and southwest.

Comment: Okay i get why $∠PTQ = \frac{\pi}{4}$ but i couldn't continue. I'm confused. Can you give me full explanation ?

Comment: Do you know the [cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)?

Comment: Yeah $ z^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xycosz $ so $ z^2 = (900)^2+(800)^2 -2(900)(800)cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$ so $ z= 657.089 $ after that i don't know what i should do. Should i take the derivative of the cosine law equation and then find $ \frac{dz}{dt}$ or what ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your **method** was fine; you were simply using the wrong equation to get a relationship amongst $z,x$, and $y$.

Comment: Okay i almost got it now, but just another question. When i get to take the derivative of cosine law equation there is $ -2xycosz $ and i get confused when i see multiple terms multiplied by each other. how do i use the product rule here ?

Comment: It’s not $\cos z$: it’s $\cos\frac{\pi}4$, which is just a constant. Thus, you’re differentiating something of the form $axy$, where $a=-2\cos\frac{\pi}4$. Just use the product rule in the usual way: the derivative is $$a\left(x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\;.$$

Comment: So it's like $ -2cos\frac{\pi}{4}(900)(800) $ and the derivative is $ -2cos\frac{\pi}{4}(900)'\cdot(800)+(900)\cdot(800)' $ so i get $ -2cos\frac{\pi}{4} $ or am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: The expression in your last comment is $0$, not $-2\cos\frac{\pi}4$. Where on earth are you getting things like $(900)'$? You’re definitely not doing the same thing that you did in your original attempt (with the wrong formula).

Comment: so $ \frac{dz}{dt}2z = \frac{dx}{dt}2x+\frac{dy}{dt}2y-2cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot(x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}) $ then i have $ \frac{dz}{dt}2(657.089)=(900)(2)(400)+(800)(2)(700)-2cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot[(700)(900)+(400)(800)] $ Is that right ?

Comment: I didn’t check the arithmetic that gave you your $z$ value, but otherwise it looks okay, yes.

Comment: I still get the wrong answer. Is this arithmetic for the z value  right ? $ z^2 = (400)^2+(700)^2-2(400)(7000)cos\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Yes, apart from the typo (extra $0$); I get a value of $z$ a hair more than $504$.

Comment: So what's wrong ? I have the final equation for $ \frac{dz}{dt}$ as this $ \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{(900)(2)(400)+(800)(2)(700)-2cos\frac{\pi}{4}(700)(900)+(400)(800)}{2(504.004)}$

Comment: I guess i got it right. No problem

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. Thank you very much. Last question, can you recommend good calculus and pre-calculus books ?

Comment: It looks okay; I make it about $492.55$. It’s been a while since I used a regular textbook to teach either of them, so I’m not a good person to ask. You might take a look at the notes available [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/), though; apart from lacking exercises, they’re really textbooks, not just notes. You’re very welcome.

Comment: Thank you sir. That website looks good :)

Comment: You’re welcome; I hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how you got ∠PTQ= π/4? Since its ∠PTQ, you used cos 400/700?